# ServiceStack group deleting and updating

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to implement ServiceStack group deleting and updating. For group deleting, the endpoint is like `~/item/{ItemIdList}`, the `ItemIdList` is of `List<Guid>` type. I already wrote the code but I'm not sure what to put into the `{ItemIdList}` part? For a single item, it is `~/item/AItem'sActualId`. What if it is a list?
And is it the correct approach or how to implement group deleting/updating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be on the `/path/info` info since the url doesn't identify a resource, it's better to be specified on the queryString on the `/items` resource collection, e.g:

```
[Route("/items", "DELETE")]
public class DeleteItems
{
    public List<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
DELETE /items?Ids={Guid1},{Guid2}
```

or via a Service Client:

```
client.Delete(new DeleteItems { Ids = new[] { Guid1, Guid2 }.ToList());
```

If you want to be able to use **ANY** HTTP Verb, your custom path can be a command like:

```
[Route("/items/delete")]
public class DeleteItems
{
    public List<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Then handle it using `Any` in your Service:

```
public object Any(DeleteItems request) { ... }
```

Which you can now call with ANY HTTP Method, e.g:

```
client.Post(new DeleteItems { Ids = new[] { Guid1, Guid2 }.ToList());
```

Comment: I would like to add that GETs should [_never_ change data (add/delete/update)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server) so I would stick with the **DELETE** verb.

Comment: @PatrickSteele Except HTML Forms only allow GET/POST so providing a Route that can be called with POST enables maximum re-use.

Comment: Agreed.  Mine was more of a "best practice" comment but you definitely make a good point about the limitations of some integration points.